# Middle name in billing/shipping name (backend + mail)

Tags: magento-1.9

I have enabled the middle name feature of Magento and it works perfectly for the complete shipping/invoice address fields, however, in the Admin interface, things like the "Bill To Name", "Ship to name", invoice names, etc are all without the middle name. I'd like to have the middle name in it, mostly because in the (default) mailtemplates the references are to that name.

For instance, when I sent out the confirmation e-mail, the shipping address has the correct name "Hendrik van Dijk", but the mail starts with "Dear Hendrik Dijk". I may be able to fix this by changing the templates, but I think it's cleaner and better to correct it so it also shows correctly in the backend.

Someone knows how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Grids please try to change `app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Resource/Order.php` -> `protected function _initVirtualGridColumns()` as you add this code:

```
$ifnullMiddle    = $adapter->getIfNullSql('{{table}}.middlename', $adapter->quote(''));
```

bellow:

```
$ifnullFirst   = $adapter->getIfNullSql('{{table}}.firstname', $adapter->quote(''));
```

and replace this:

```
$concatAddress = $adapter->getConcatSql(array($ifnullFirst, $adapter->quote(' '), $ifnullLast));
```

with this:

```
$concatAddress = $adapter->getConcatSql(array($ifnullFirst, $adapter->quote(' '), $ifnullMiddle, $adapter->quote(' '), $ifnullLast));
```

You also have to change `app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Resource/Order/Creditmemo.php` and `app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Resource/Order/Invoice.php` which are almost the same as `Order.php`. Please keep in mind that most probably this will work only on new orders (because tables `sales_flat_..._grid` are already generated for the old orders).

For "Dear, Customer Name" please try to change `app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order.php` -> `public function getCustomerName()` as you replace this:

```
$customerName = $this->getCustomerFirstname() . ' ' . $this->getCustomerLastname();
```

with this:

```
$customerName = $this->getCustomerFirstname() . ' ' . $this->getCustomerMiddlename() . ' ' . $this->getCustomerLastname();
```

It's recommended to make your own module which rewrites these classes or at least copy these files to `app/code/local` and then to modify them.

Comment: Thanks for this solution - I knew that programatically it should normally be able to solve this, but in my opinion it's stupid that there is an option for middlename that is not implemented in a consequent manner.

Comment: Yes, they missed this. It happens. :)